# How to get page language (hreflang) in JavaScript and add it as a parameter to a link

Tags: javascript, hreflang

As an example, I have this code that is able to add the title of a page as a parameter to a link that is identified as an ID. I would like to be able to do the same for the language of the page. Thanks for your help!

```
<script>
const linkIds = [
  'Your_link_id'
];
linkIds.forEach(id => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {    
    const link = document.querySelector('#' + id);
    if (link) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      const href = link.getAttribute('href');
      const pageTitle = 
        document
          .title
          .replace(/\s+/g, '_')
          .replace(/&/g, '')
          .toLowerCase()
      const newHref = `${href}?your_parameter_name=${pageTitle}`;
      link.setAttribute('href', newHref);
    }
  }, 20);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get language of the page you have to get `lang` property from the document element. I created an example code which gets and sets the language of the page. You can save the output to some variable and create a link with it.

```js
let lang = document.documentElement.lang

console.log(lang)
// output: en

document.documentElement.lang = 'af'

console.log(document.documentElement.lang)

// output: af
```

Answer (score -1):

I added this as a new answer because I am not sure what I am suppose to do (this fact itself shows that this is not very well written question) but I will try.

So your script uses some array of IDs. Then it creates an interval for each ID that constantly updates the `href` attribute of element with that ID with some value. I don't know why would you do that as `pageTitle` or `language` is not changing over time but I might just stop asking so here is the edited code:

```html
<script>

    const linkIds = [
        'Your_link_id'
    ];

    // here I get the lanugage of the page
    let lang = document.documentElement.lang;

    linkIds.forEach(id => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {    
            const link = document.querySelector('#' + id);
            if (link) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                const href = link.getAttribute('href');

                // here I set the language where page title was before 
                const newHref = `${href}?your_parameter_name=${lang}`;

                link.setAttribute('href', newHref);
            }
        }, 20);
    });

</script>
```

Try it and report back. If you need to use such a complex script, it might do you good to actually learn Javascript.